# Display user’s selected directory path from 'Browse' button using tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to link the user's selected folder path so that it will be placed inside the text field to the right. I've tried several different methods to no avail. Here's what I've got so far. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's where I'm at.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class ParentWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.master.minsize(550,175)
        self.master.maxsize(550,175)

        self.master.title("Check Files")
        self.master.configure(bg="#F0F0F0")

        #DEFINE BUTTONS
        self.btn_browse1 = tk.Button(self.master,width=12,height=1,text="Browse...",command = lambda: 
        browse())
        self.btn_browse1.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=(15,0),pady=(40,0),sticky=W)
        self.btn_browse2 = tk.Button(self.master,width=12,height=1,text="Browse...",command = lambda: 
        browse())
        self.btn_browse2.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=(15,0),pady=(10,0),sticky=W)
        self.btn_checkForFiles = tk.Button(self.master,width=12,height=2,
        text="Check for files...",command = lambda: check())
        self.btn_checkForFiles.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=(15,0),pady=(10,0),sticky=W)
        self.btn_close = tk.Button(self.master,width=12,height=2,text="Close Program")
        self.btn_close.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=(15,0),pady=(10,0),sticky=S+E)
        
        #DEFINE TEXT BOXES
        self.txt_browse1 = tk.Entry(self.master,width=65,text="")
        self.txt_browse1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=(25,0),pady=(35,0),sticky=W)
        self.txt_browse2 = tk.Entry(self.master,width=65,text="")
        self.txt_browse2.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=(25,0),pady=(5,0),sticky=W)


def browse(): 
    dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = ParentWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _to no avail_ What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `browse()` function a method under the class ParentWindow, so it can access all the widgets of the window. Then, you just need to insert the name of the directory to the entry widget. Better even, make one browse function for each:

```
class ParentWindow(Frame):
    ###
    ### Your code
    ### 

    def browse1(self): 
        dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.txt_browse1.delete("1",END)
        self.txt_browse1.insert("1",dirname)
        
    def browse2(self): 
        dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.txt_browse2.delete("1",END)
        self.txt_browse2.insert("1",dirname)
```

Note that you will have to call the function as a method, if you do so. So, change command argument in the button definitions to `self.browse1/2`:

```
        self.btn_browse1 = tk.Button(self.master,width=12,height=1,text="Browse...",command = lambda: self.browse1())

        self.btn_browse2 = tk.Button(self.master,width=12,height=1,text="Browse...",command = lambda: self.browse2())
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way to do it is to pass your `browse()` call the `textvariable` associated with each `Entry` widget, the all it has to do is assign the value returned from `filedialog.askdirectory()` to it.

Here's a modified version of your code that does exactly that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class ParentWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.master.minsize(550,175)
        self.master.maxsize(550,175)

        self.master.title("Check Files")
        self.master.configure(bg="#F0F0F0")

        #DEFINE BUTTONS
        self.btn_browse1 = tk.Button(self.master, width=12, height=1, text="Browse...",
                                     command=lambda: browse(path1))
        self.btn_browse1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(15,0), pady=(40,0), sticky=W)
        self.btn_browse2 = tk.Button(self.master, width=12, height=1, text="Browse...",
                                     command=lambda: browse(path2))
        self.btn_browse2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(15,0), pady=(10,0), sticky=W)
        self.btn_checkForFiles = tk.Button(self.master, width=12, height=2,
                                           text="Check for files...",
                                           command=lambda: check())
        self.btn_checkForFiles.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(15,0), pady=(10,0), sticky=W)
        self.btn_close = tk.Button(self.master, width=12, height=2, text="Close Program")
        self.btn_close.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=(15,0), pady=(10,0), sticky=S+E)

        #DEFINE TEXT BOXES
        path1 = tk.StringVar(value='')
        path2 = tk.StringVar(value='')
        self.txt_browse1 = tk.Entry(self.master, width=65, textvariable=path1)
        self.txt_browse1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(25,0), pady=(35,0), sticky=W)
        self.txt_browse2 = tk.Entry(self.master, width=65, textvariable=path2)
        self.txt_browse2.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(25,0), pady=(5,0), sticky=W)


def browse(pathvar):
    dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
    pathvar.set(dirname)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = ParentWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```